# How can I find an SKSpriteNode's velocity as x and y values?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am working on developing an platformer game and am trying to find the user-controlled character's velocity in x and y values. The purpose is to detect if the player is falling, jumping, running, or standing. For example, if the player leaves a ledge, I want to be able to detect the change in his y value to determine if he is falling or jumping and display the correct texture. (I realize I can detect a jump based on whether or not the jump command was given, and I can detect if he leaves a platform based on "didEndContact", but I would have more consistent control if I could change player states based on the direction they are moving.) Hopefully I explained what I'm trying to do well enough. Let me know if I need to explain better or if there is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: The velocity is a property of SKPhysicsBody: `var velocity : CGVector = sprite.physicsBody!.velocity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the property [`velocity`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/velocity) from the `SKPhysicsBody` of your node.

This vector stores the current velocity of the body.

You can then access the `x` and `y` value by using either `velocity.dx` or `velocity.dy`. (For example in your `update()` method).